# MQTTNet UseApplicationMessageReceivedHandler not firing

Tags: mqtt, mqttnet

I am doing a POC so here is the quick and dirty code.  I use MQTT.fx desktop client to test Pub/Sub to my MQTT Server.  Works fine.  I can publish/subscribe to my topic.  I can publish from another mqtt client and I get the messages.  When using this code, I do not receive anything when I publish messages from MQTT.fx or any other publishers.  I will receive something if I publish with the mqttClient (if you uncomment the line).  I am scratching my head...
Can someone help?  Thanks.

```
class Program
{
    private static CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource(); //TODO create token using the Timeout delay from config
    private static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var factory = new MqttFactory();
        var mqttClient = factory.CreateMqttClient();
        var options = new MqttClientOptionsBuilder()
            .WithClientId("MyClientIDHere")
            .WithTcpServer("IPAddressHere", 1883)
            //.WithCredentials("Wbo", string.Empty)
            //.WithTls()
            .WithCleanSession()
            .Build();
        try
        {
            mqttClient.UseApplicationMessageReceivedHandler(async e =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("### RECEIVED APPLICATION MESSAGE ###");
                Console.WriteLine($"+ Topic = {e.ApplicationMessage.Topic}");
                Console.WriteLine($"+ Payload = {Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.ApplicationMessage.Payload)}");
                Console.WriteLine($"+ QoS = {e.ApplicationMessage.QualityOfServiceLevel}");
                Console.WriteLine($"+ Retain = {e.ApplicationMessage.Retain}");
                Console.WriteLine();
            });
            mqttClient.UseConnectedHandler(async e =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("### CONNECTED WITH SERVER ###");

                // Subscribe to a topic
                await mqttClient.SubscribeAsync(new TopicFilterBuilder().WithTopic("MyClientIDHere/Device_2/Instance_1").Build());

                Console.WriteLine("### SUBSCRIBED ###");
            });
            await mqttClient.ConnectAsync(options, cts.Token);
           // UNCOMMENT AND YOU WILL RECEIVE A MESSAGE Task.Run(() => mqttClient.PublishAsync("MyClientIDHere/Device_2/Instance_1","met=Temperature~data=29"));

        }

        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("task cancelled");   
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With the latest version of MQTTnet I could not reproduce your issue, it seems to work here. I'm using a mosquitto MQTT server which is located on another server than where I run my program.

Your code looks good. You can improve some, by subscribing to the topics before connecting.